# Can You Kill The Landowner?

Tags: sir-you-are-being-hunted

I recently purchased Sir You Are Being Hunter and have actually being doing quite well for a sir who lives his life drinking tea and making robots that hunt himself.  After saving my game I noticed the landowner over in the woods next to me so I thought, "I must say that landowner needs to be taken care of immediately!"  So I rushed over, loaded my gun and shot him a few times.  I got direct hits two times and then the robots started coming.  I thought that maybe he must have a lot more health so I shot a few more times but still nothing!  I then met an unfortunate demise with bullets riddled through my body but that made me wonder, "Can you kill the landowner?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from all evidence, it would seem that the Landowner cannot be killed. This is because of a choice by the developers no doubt, and may serve to help you to realize how fragile and delicate your survival is in Sir, You Are Being Hunted.

A video of someone attempting to kill the Landowner:
[Attempted Landowner Kill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmdP1OkSgRU)

He was not successful, and used '38 Rifle Shells, 28 Shotgun Shells and 1 Dynamite' or something to that effect.

It is, however, possible that there is a way to kill him that relates to the plot. I have not played the game, so I could not answer from personal experience.

Answer (score -2):

I remember I was going around then I heard shooting and I was like "what is going on" I look round and there are a group of hunters shooting the landowner, eventually I saw the landowner flop to the ground I was super shocked I'm like the landowner just got killed by the hunters they all riddled me after so I never got to see what you could get from the landowner. That day I realised"perhaps only the other robots can kill the landowner" or whether it's just too many bullets for the landowner to handle.

Comment: The question is if the player can kill the landowner. Also, please use punctuation.